# Dockerhub fails to build my Dockerfile

Tags: docker, apt-get, dockerhub

I made a Dockerfile that works great on my machine, but the build is failing on dockerhub.

The dockerhub error is:

```
Build failed: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y curl gcc libc6-dev libc6 --no-install-recommends && exit 0' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

That step builds fine on my (ARM) machine, however it does produce a warning:

```
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
```

*(I'm unable to silence that, tried fixes that worked for other people)*.

Here is the dockerhub build (includes Dockerfile and error): https://hub.docker.com/r/askmike/golang-arm/builds/bnc9b3xqgedfbeboix2ezv4/

---

- Question 1: If there is warning from apt-get, will that consider the build failed? (I can't find what the return code would be).
- Question 2: Is there maybe another error in the dockerhub build that does not happen on my machine? If so, how can I ever troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the cause of the build failure is:

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Your base image is `resin/rpi-raspbian:jessie` which is an ARM image.  Docker Hub is an x86_64 build platform.  So you will not be able to use Docker Hub to build your images.

Comment: Yes it's an ARM build. But the ARM stuff comes from another image which builds fine on dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/resin/rpi-raspbian

Comment: That image is hosted on Docker Hub but it's not *built* on Docker Hub.  The owner is presumably building it somewhere else and then pushing it on to Docker Hub.

Comment: This image may be a useful alternative - https://hub.docker.com/r/jsurf/rpi-raspbian/ - its description has a link to more details.

Comment: ahhhhhh I didn't understand that a non automatic build is one that you can build locally and simply upload. I'll just do that instead! Thanks :)

Comment: Another thing which I didn't see: on the build page you can scroll down to see the actual logs. I searched for them but could not find them anywhere..